# Open a website  triggered on an outgoing call

Tags: android

Is there's some way to launch an Android user's browser when they place a call to a specific telephone number without any application install on his smart phone?

Comment: Any magician maybe guide you in Right Direction

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible without using a custom dialer program.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible without having any applications installed on the user's smart phone. You need an application with a broadcast receiver to listen for [ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_NEW_OUTGOING_CALL), inspect the provided phone number and then start a new intent to launch the browser.